# Python how to remove path from sys.path_importer_cache (invalid namespace import)

Tags: python, import, anaconda, namespace-package

I have a weird phenomenon (Windows, python 3.8.5): I have a folder: `c:\myfolder`. Somehow this folder got into the `sys.path_importer_cache`, and now every subfolder in c:\myfolder can be imported as namespace packages.
So for example, there is this subfolder: `c:\myfolder\foo\`
And if I try to import foo, I get this:

```py
import foo
foo
<module 'foo' (namespace)>
foo.__path__
_NamespacePath(['c:\\myfolder\\foo'])
```

and its loader is a `NamespaceLoader`.

The problem is, that  `foo` itself is a package, that is installed into the site-packages, and now it does not get imported from there, because this weird namespace package beats it.

What have I messed up? Where do I look? I could only find this hint, that `c:\myfolder` is in the `sys.path_importer_cache`.
But why did it get there? How can I remove it? (I tried `importlib.invalidate_caches()`, no success...)
One more hint: if I run python in isolated mode (`python -I`), this problem goes away. However, I don't have anything in my user-site that could cause it (as far as I know.)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been figured out... I python in Anaconda, and I have launched the Anaconda Prompt (with condabin/activate) in the c:\myfolder as start folder. That's why it got into the path_importer_cache... If I start it simply in c:, the problem goes away.